# Run application maximized maximizes the splash screen but not the mainform

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

In my application, first a splash screen is created and shown, then after the MainForm (as normal sized window).

If I want to start the Mainform maximized, I crated a desktop link to my application with start "maximized".

But it maximizes the splash screen first (which I do not want), and afterward the Mainform is not shown maximized.

How can I achieve, that, when I want to start my application maximized, the splash screen remains its size and the Mainform is maximized?

```
public FormMain()
{
    splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
    splashScreen.lblStatus.Text = "Initialisierung...";
    splashScreen.Show();
    splashScreen.Refresh();

    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeGui();
}
```

Comment: How did you implement the splash screen?

Comment: Add the code to the question with code formatting.

Comment: The Show() order matters, the first one gets the shortcut preference.  Showing the splash screen in the Load event handler gives you the order that you want.  If that's not practical then tinker with the WindowState property.  It will have the expected value in the Load event handler of the splash screen, store it in a variable to know what to do with the main window.

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation. So I have to reorder the show (first the mainform) to achieve the maximize the Mainform properly(?)